# Adding a class and clearing all other instances of elements that are not siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to be able to add the class `accordion-minus` on click, and at the same time clear all instances of the class on all elements except `this`. Currently it's working, but only if I toggle one by one, if I go from one to another it breaks. 
This is my markup:

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel-group panel-group-pdp" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
          <h4 class="panel-title product-accordion-title text-uppercase">
            <a id="{{content.static.productDetailsToggleId}}" class="collapsed pdp-accord-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">{{content.static.productDetailsText}}<img class="accordion-plus" src="{{meta.assetsPath}}img/plus79.png" alt="accordion content">
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
          <div class="panel-body panel-body-pdp">
            <ul>
              {{#each content.product.details}}
                <li>{{text}}</li>
              {{/each}}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
          <h4 class="panel-title product-accordion-title text-uppercase">
            <a id="{{content.static.deliveryReturnsToggleId}}" class="collapsed pdp-accord-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">{{content.static.deliveryAndReturnsText}}<img class="accordion-plus" src="{{meta.assetsPath}}img/plus79.png" alt="accordion content">
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
          <div class="panel-body panel-body-pdp">
            <p>
              {{content.static.standardDeliveryText}}
            </p>
            <p>
              {{content.static.expressDeliveryText}}
            </p>
            <p>
              {{content.static.freeReturnsText}}
            </p>
            <p>
              {{content.static.moreDeliveryInfoText}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".pdp-accord-toggle").click(function() {
  if($('.accordion-plus').hasClass('accordion-minus') === false) {
    // $(this).find('.accordion-plus').not(this).removeClass('accordion-minus');
    $(this).find('.accordion-plus').addClass('accordion-minus');
  } else {
    $(this).find('.accordion-plus').removeClass('accordion-minus');
  }
});
```

Comment: simplest way might be to just remove the class from everything, then add it to the element you want it on. I'm somewhat confused as to exactly what you're trying to do, a js fiddle might help.

Comment: Can you setup a sample jsfiddle without unnecessary details?